# Using drawable resources

Tags: android, bitmap, drawable, xml-drawable

I have this problem, see the trace stack:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(2410): Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #5: <bitmap> requires a valid src attribute
```

My xml file looks like:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/btn_1"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

btn_1 is another xml file in drawable resources
When i'm using an image(*.png) instead of xml drawable it's ok.

Can I use a drawable resource as src to bitmap?
Just in case here is my btn_1.xml file. It doesn't work even if btn_1 file have no items.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_arrow_bg_red"/>
<item>
    <bitmap
        android:gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/btn_arrow_white" />
</item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: thx. but hmm. what I should do? i need to place one drawable xml resource above another, but my resource is scaling... what i must do to avoid scaling an xml drawable resource? and <item>have no gravity parameter...

Comment: I got this error (`<bitmap> requires a valid src attribute`) when I use **vector image** for bitmap. My solution is - Use @Santiago Rivas answer - Or user another image (not vector image)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You cant have an *xml drawable* as source for bitmap. Because for example if it was possible, then it could mistakenly create a black-hole by calling xml to itself.

Lets suppose, you have an xml drawable **A** which has a bitmap whos source is drawable **B**. But in drawable **B**, it has a bitmap whos source is drawable **A**. This will create a circular loop which cant be resolved. That is why you need to provide an image as a source for bitmap to avoid any confusion

Comment: Thanks for this Waqas, I have the exact same question (but didn't merge as this is marked as answered) - but I'm asking for the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10055892/preventing-shapes-scaling-in-a-layeredlist-with-or-without-using-bitmap

Comment: @waqaslam, your answer is correct: you can't have an XML drawable as the source for a bitmap tag. What I find confusing is your explanation: the circular reference can happen in any context when referencing XML resources. It seems to me it's a design constraint in the framework

Comment: The second part is just irrelevant

Comment: Why this code works on API 18?

Answer (score 129):

To avoid error: Binary XML file line #XXX:  requires a valid src attribute

inside a layer-list, use:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image" />
```

instead of:

```
<item>
  <bitmap android:src="@drawable/image"/>
</item>
```

Comment: but what if I need tileMode?

Comment: Yes, what if I need tileMode, tint, or any of the other many many attributes on bitmap...?

Comment: It is real solution for me!!

Comment: This shows my drawable, but it always shows it full-screen sized rather than its normal size on API 28.

Comment: This solution doesn't explain the difference between them, and it breaks on new api versions

Comment: works just fine!

Answer (score 15):

**Minimum SDK:** API 23

### drawable/yourDrawable.xml

In the following code I have a vector as a background as the first item and in the second item centered logo with a custom size above the background.

```
<layer-list
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_in_svg_1">

    </item>
    <item
        android:width="200dp"
        android:height="60dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:drawable="@drawable/logo_in_svg_2"/>
</layer-list>
```

*Note:* The cumulative distribution as of today from API 23 is 84.9%. So you might consider an alternative for lower APIs

GL

[Source](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards)

Comment: Note that width and height you only can use them if min is higher than 23

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Updated response. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use selector for changing tint attribute, create selector for color only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_activated="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/green" />
</selector>
```

And then use it as color in android:tint

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:tint="@color/tint_menu_item"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_home" />
```