# customize toggle button on Android

Tags: android, togglebutton

I customized the Toggle button by using a drawable defined by using a selector. I use this drawable as background for the Toggle button.

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/mailbox:toggle_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_background"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical" />
```

The toggle_background is defined here:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/img1"
            android:state_checked="true" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/img2"
            android:state_checked="false" />    
    </selector>
```

The problem is that the image is always stretched. Is there a way to define an image for the two states that is not stretched?

What I need is a background that will be stretched and in the center of the button an icon that must not be stretched.

Is it possible?

Comment: Show the screenshot and your related code of `ToggleButton`

Comment: You have to use nine patch(.9 patch) image .

Comment: 9 patched are not usable since I need the non stretched icon to be in the center

Comment: remove the android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: I need the weight to be defined because I need to stretched the background

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did the same task this way, the button:

```
        <ToggleButton  android:id="@+id/mlAbout"
            android:textOn="@string/about"
            android:textOff="@string/about"
            android:background="@drawable/ml_about" />
```

@drawable/ml_about:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_bg_top"></item>
    <item android:left="10dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/waiting_status_btn"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|left" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

@drawable/list_bg_top background image that will be stretched and @drawable/waiting_status_btn is the icon the will not be stretched with the widget

Comment: The solution is implicitly given in the answer. The way to get a non stretched image is using a bitmap and not a drawable. I had to modify the proposed solution to allow having two different image for the different state: I used a drawable in the layer-list and then I defined the drawable by using a selector that for each state uses a bitmap

Comment: This is incorrect - if you want ToggleButton to behave with standard states. Supposing your waiting_status_btn is an XML drawable: You can't have an XML drawable as a src for a bitmap. As stated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788726/using-drawable-resources

Answer (score 13):

This is my final solution.

In the layout:

```
<ToggleButton
    android:id="@+id/mailbox:toggle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"     
    android:background="@drawable/toggle_drawable_layers"/>
```

in the toggle_drawable_layers.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_drawable_bkg"></item>
    <item android:left="10dp" android:drawable="@drawable/toggle_drawable_left"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
</layer-list>
```

in the toggle_drawable_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bitmap_checked"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/bitmap_unchecked"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />
    </item>        
</selector>
```

Comment: what is the toggle_drawable_bkg? when it comes?

Comment: Your solution works. But I found that if you use `android:background="@null"` and `android:button="@drawable/toggle_drawable_left"` you can skip the use of the third xml file `toggle_drawable_layers.xml`. The images will not be stretched.

Answer (score 2):

Just use bitmaps instead of drawables in your selector like so (no need to use layers):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/img1"
        android:state_checked="true" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/img2"
        android:state_checked="false" />    
</selector>
```

Also, don't forget to declare 
        android:textOff=""
        android:textOn="" 
in your ToggleButton declaration

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to overcome the issue of stretching:

Just convert the image into a [Nine-Patch image](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html), where the stretchable areas are just on all sides of the image.

Then Android will stretch the image only in invisible areas, and keep the visible image unchanged.