# Android: Square buttons like AVG

Tags: android, button, user-interface, transparency

I have been doing a lot of research about, how I can make my app look half decent in terms of the buttons, and I have decided that I will be using square buttons that are transparent apart from the border.

Does anyone know of any tutorials for something similar. I have searched the web but I cannot really find what I am after.

This is basically what I am trying to achieve. 
[image: avg example]
<sub>(source: [itproportal.com](http://cdn.itproportal.com/photos/avg_mobile_550_px_contentfullwidth.png))</sub>

Comment: if yours button are in a grid than make a custom gridview with these custom buttons

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the borders, I'd use a [9 patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html).
For the buttons, you seem to be using [ToggleButtons](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ToggleButton.html).
You can customize their aspect: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726289/customize-toggle-button-on-android).

Comment: Fantastic, I completely forgot about 9 patch. (been a while) Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Nice to see such an enthusiasm!

Comment: It's been over 2 years since I have done anything like this. Getting back into it is proving challenging.

Comment: You might be able to help me with another puzzling task. I am trying to create a decent looking background that can fit all devices. Check out the image below. Any idea on how they do it?http://www.letsgodigital.org/images/artikelen/1028/avg-uninstaller-app.jpg

Comment: It happens... Going to study the image.

Comment: I edited comment after. http://www.letsgodigital.org/images/artikelen/1028/avg-uninstaller-app.jpg

Comment: OK. If you only had 1 string, I'd say: use a TextView with a compund drawable. But you have 2 stings, so, you must add another TextView under the one with the drawable. You can put them either on a LinearLayout or in a RelativeLayout. I prefer the latter. Set the first TextVew as **layout_alignParentTop="true"** and **layout_CenterInParent="true"**. The second one should have its layout_below="@id/txtTopLeftButton". Now, replicate this 4 times inside a RelativeLayout and play with relative positions (toRighOf, toLeftOf, below, ...)

Comment: and center this RelativeLayout in its overall container (this might be a Vertical LinearLayout). So, you can put a TextView to be the title, ontop of this button panel

Comment: I see..... Great. Thanks. Time to get the headphones on and get stuck in.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your custom view with gradient background. View should consists click listener.