# android drawable bitmap xml

Tags: android, bitmap, android-drawable

My drawable, I want to repeat (/drawable/dot.xml):

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <solid android:color="@color/black" />

    <size
        android:height="32dp"
        android:width="32dp" />

</shape>
```

My repeat drawable (/drawable/dot_repeat.xml):

```
<bitmap
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/dot"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

But now, Android Studio shows

```
<bitmap> requires a valid src attribute
```

If my src is a png file, it works like a expected. Does someone have an idea? I don't want to create a PNG for my background.

Comment: see here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788726/using-drawable-resources

Comment: ^^ The above one is good .Please add  android:dither="true" in your  dot_repeat.xml

Comment: @Amiya Into which XML? The first or second one?

Comment: @mars3142 I updated my comments . Don't know it will be working or not .

Comment: @mars3142 Logcat generates any exceptions ?

Comment: See the comment of @RobiKumarTomar - It's a limitation of the framework :(