# Change Spinner dropdown icon

Tags: android, android-spinner

The solutions I found to change the spinner dropdown icon where all:

**1. create a custom drawable**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/vector_drawable_ic_dropdown_black" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/vector_drawable_ic_dropdown_black" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/vector_drawable_ic_dropdown_black" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/vector_drawable_ic_dropdown_black" />
</selector>
```

**2. Set the drawable as the spinner background:**

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:background="@drawable/custom_spinner_icon"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary" />
```

And the result is:

[image]

As you can see this is not an acceptable solution since the icon needs to be right aligned and not stretched.

What can I do to make the icon not stretch and align it right?

**EDIT**

Since there are no working solutions yet I guess I have to specify my question.
This is how my Spinner looks using the standard theme:

```
<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/products_download_spinner_language"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"
    android:paddingTop="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/textcolorprimary"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" />
```

[image]

And everything I want (it is really not much I guess) is changing the arrow. I don't want that arrow in the right bottom corner to be displayed, I want this arrow to be displayed vertically centered at the right:

[image]

And every solution which i tried until now:

[Spinner Dropdown Arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30712235/spinner-dropdown-arrow)

[How to set dropdown arrow in spinner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422802/how-to-set-dropdown-arrow-in-spinner)

simply weren't working. They had stretched icons or the bottom line was missing or something else went totally wrong. I just want another arrow.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20422802/how-to-set-dropdown-arrow-in-spinner

Comment: It's so ridiculous that this hasn't been resolved yet :/

Comment: @Mulgard Were you able to figure out how to do it with vector drawable? The accepted answer seems to be using `bitmap` (using .png or something) and your question seems to have vector drawables.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

Try applying following style to your spinner using

```
style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
```

//**Spinner Style**:

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bg_spinner</item>
</style>
```

//**bg_spinner.xml**
  Replace the arrow_down_gray with your arrow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>

        <layer-list>

            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                    <stroke android:width="0.33dp" android:color="#0fb1fa" />

                    <corners android:radius="0dp" />

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>

            <item android:right="5dp">

                <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/arrow_down_gray" />

            </item>

        </layer-list>

    </item>

</selector>
```

Comment: how to remove top right and left border? just need bottom border.

Comment: Do you know where arrow_down_gray is? I am looking for the file! Thanks

Comment: This can be any arrow icon which you want to use. Anyway I have attached that as well, please see here http://oi64.tinypic.com/2jb3b88.jpg

Comment: What if @drawable/arrow_down_gray is vector?

Comment: @Lester I am unable to add vector there. Instead when I try directly using the vector as item, `<item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down_greay" android:gravity="center_vertical|right" />`, it stretches on some devices still. Were you able to come up with a solution?

Comment: It did not work with custom Spinner Adapter with a custom layout with image and text

Comment: how to add paddingEnd to the drawable? The drawable is stuck to the end of the spinner. I need to add some padding to the drawable

Comment: @Lester paste the code of that vector drawable in the place of bitmap line

Comment: @Lester Don't use the Bitmap tag inside of an item tag, use item attributes directly: ```<item
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:gravity="end|center_vertical"
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_vector"
        />```

Comment: @milosmms, that will work for API>=23, and you can dont have to add android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp"  in API>24, but for API<23, the arrow stretchs. Any body else have a solution using vector for api<23?. I try using the bitmap method, but it fails in API23

Answer (score 42):

Add theme to spinner

```
<Spinner style="@style/SpinnerTheme"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Add spinnerTheme to styles.xml

```
<style name="SpinnerTheme" parent="android:Widget.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background</item>
</style>
```

Add New -> "Vector Asset" to drawable with e.g. "ic_keyboard_arrow_down_24dp"

Add spinner_background.xml to drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_24dp" android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:right="5dp"/>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: looking stretched on android OS 5.0. Any lead?

Answer (score 20):

For this you can use **.9 Patch Image** and just simply set it in to background.

```
android:background="@drawable/spin"
```

Here i'll give you .9patch image. try with this.

[image]
[image]

Right click on image and click Save Image as

set image name like this : **anyname.9.png** and hit save.

Enjoy.. Happy Coading. :)

Comment: Im using svg's. Much better than .9 Patch Image.

Comment: I think in this case a .9patch image is better than an svg. Using a 9patch you could stretch only a transparent pixel from the left border, and keep the rest of the image at the original size. I don't know if that's possible using svg, but I would definitely give a try to this answer.

Comment: @Mulgard, you should take a look to the original implementation and the format of the icon used. If I'm not wrong, the default implementation uses a 9patch

Comment: I think this is the best solution, without the need to play with the mysterious android theme

Answer (score 12):

We can manage it by hiding the icon as i did:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/fragment_filter_sp_users"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:background="@color/colorTransparent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
            android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
            android:contentDescription="@null"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_bottom"
    />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: This is simple and does the job imo. Also works just fine with an SVG obviously.

Answer (score 4):

You need to create custom background like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item>
                <shape>
                    <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear"/>

                    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#504a4b"/>

                    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>

                    <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp"/>
                </shape>
            </item>
            <item>
                <bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right" android:src="@drawable/drop_down"/> // you can place your dropdown image
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Then create **style** for spinner like this:

```
<style name="spinner_style">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/YOURCUSTOMBACKGROUND</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">5dp</item>
</style>
```

after that apply this style to your **spinner**

Comment: This solution aint working. No icon is showing until you click the spinner. and after that a huge dropdown icon is showing up inside the dropdown menu.

Comment: how to add paddingEnd to the drawable? The drawable is stuck to the end of the spinner. I need to add some padding to the drawable.

Comment: If using vector drawables you need to use `item` instead of `bitmap`

Comment: for padding add this line of code <item android:right="10dp">
                <bitmap .........................

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to define a custom background in xml? decreasing the Spinner background width which is doing your arrow look like that.

Define a layer-list with a rectangle background and your custom arrow icon:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/color_white" />
            <corners android:radius="2.5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="64dp">
         <bitmap android:gravity="right|center_vertical"  
             android:src="@drawable/custom_spinner_icon">
         </bitmap>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3):

dummy.xml(remember image size should be less)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item>
            <layer-list android:opacity="transparent">
                <item android:width="60dp" android:gravity="left" android:start="20dp">
                    <bitmap  android:src="@drawable/down_button_dummy_dummy" android:gravity="left"/>
                </item>
            </layer-list>
        </item>
    </selector>
```

layout file snippet be like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        >
     <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dummy">

     </Spinner>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[click to see result layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMgCu.png)

Answer (score 2):

Without Using ANY Drop down Using your Drop Down ICON

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item>
    <layer-list>
        <item>
            <shape>
               <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" /><!--For gradient background-->

                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#FFF" /><!--For Border background-->

                <corners android:radius="0dp" /><!--For background corner-->

                <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="6dp" android:top="3dp" /><!--For padding for all sides-->
            </shape>
        </item>
        <item>
            <bitmap android:gravity="center|right" android:src="@drawable/ic_down_arrow" /> // Replace with your Icon

        </item>
    </layer-list>
</item>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have managed to do the following:

[image]

Create this drawable file with this name **radio_button_background_drawable**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list>
            <item android:drawable="@drawable/vector_down_arrow" android:gravity="end" android:right="5dp" />
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Add it to the spinner background:

```
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/id_type_SP"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/radio_button_background_drawable"
            android:inputType="number"
            tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick to set the spinner background to a transparent color to hide the default spinner arrow:

```
<Spinner
    ....
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

Then create a custom spinner resource item (for the closed state); set your arrow drawable to the `android:drawableEnd` `TextView`:

spinner_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<CheckedTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingVertical="4dp"
    app:drawableEndCompat="@drawable/chevron_down"
    app:drawableRightCompat="@drawable/chevron_down"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:singleLine="true"/>
```

Set that to the adapter:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(context,
         R.layout.spinner_item, myItems);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want change dropdown icon with any vector drawable you can try this.

You should define `spinnerStyle` and `android:spinnerItemStyle` in your (styles.xml or themes.xml).

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light">
    ...
    <item name="spinnerStyle">@style/AppTheme.Spinner</item>
    <item name="android:spinnerItemStyle">@style/AppTheme.Spinner.Item</item>
    ...
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Spinner" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">start</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Spinner.Item" parent="Widget.AppCompat.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="drawableRightCompat">@drawable/baseline_keyboard_arrow_down_24</item>
</style>
```

That's all, now you can use Spinner any layout.

```
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/exampleArray" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I have had a lot of difficulty with this as I have a custom spinner, if I setBackground then the Drawable would stretch. My solution to this was to add a drawable to the right of the Spinner TextView. Heres a code snippet from my Custom Spinner. 
The trick is to Override getView and customize the Textview as you wish.

```
public class NoTextSpinnerArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private String text = "0";

    public NoTextSpinnerArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
    }

    public void updateText(String text){
        this.text = text;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public String getText(){
        return text;
    }

    @NonNull
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        TextView textView = view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(16);
        textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp, 0);

        textView.setGravity(Gravity.END);
        textView.setText(text);
        return view;
    }
}
```

You also need to set the Spinner background to transparent:

```
<lifeunlocked.valueinvestingcheatsheet.views.SelectAgainSpinner
            android:id="@+id/saved_tickers_spinner"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="248dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />
```

and my custom spinner if you want it....

```
public class SelectAgainSpinner extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner {
    public SelectAgainSpinner(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SelectAgainSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SelectAgainSpinner(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPopupBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background) {
        super.setPopupBackgroundDrawable(background);
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position, boolean animate) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position, animate);
        if (sameSelected) {
            // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
            if (getOnItemSelectedListener() != null) {
                getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setSelection(int position) {
        boolean sameSelected = position == getSelectedItemPosition();
        super.setSelection(position);
        if (sameSelected) {
            // Spinner does not call the OnItemSelectedListener if the same item is selected, so do it manually now
            if (getOnItemSelectedListener() != null) {
                getOnItemSelectedListener().onItemSelected(this, getSelectedView(), position, getSelectedItemId());
            }
        }
    }
}
```