# How can I change the arrow on a Spinner?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, spinner

I would like to format a Spinner so the arrows look like the following:

[image: Spinners]

Any suggestions on a way to make the arrows look like they do in the clip?

Comment: Does this link answers your question? https://androiddvlpr.com/custom-spinner-android/

Comment: Looks good. Will try it out tomorrow and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Here is the answer that helped me the most: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411637/change-spinner-dropdown-icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37411637/change-spinner-dropdown-icon)