# Setting custom dropdown arrow in Android Spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I'm trying to customize the arrow image in a spinner. Here's my code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
spin = (Spinner) inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner, null);
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Choice>(context, R.layout.nitro_spinner_item, choicesArr);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.multiline_spinner_dropdown_item);
spin.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and R.layout.nitro_spinner_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@android:id/text1"
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_acf"
      android:ellipsize="marquee"
      android:singleLine="true"
      android:textAlignment="inherit"/>
```

But here's what I get:
[image]

I see my custom image, along with the normal Android dropdown arrow. I used the answer here as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30336734/1642002 . Where does the stock dropdown image come from if I've overridden the text view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028202/android-add-arrow-image-to-spinner

Comment: maybe is part of the background. What happens if your add  `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` to the xml

Comment: @Blackbelt: I tried that, the arrow must not be part of the textview itself.

Comment: Did you figure this out?  I have a similar use-case for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the background of the Spinner widget to transparent:

```
<Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```