# Android place drawables in corners XML

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

I'm struggling to create pure xml drawable, that would align 4 other xml-drawables in the 4 corners (top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right) of the root one. I thought of using `<layer-list>` with `<bitmap android:gravity="bottom|right">`  bit it turned out that [you can't use xml as bitmap src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788726/using-drawable-resources). What else can I try to do?

Comment: what botmaps are you talking about? why pure xml?

Comment: @pskink I'm talking about `<bitmap>` tag which you can declare inside `<item>` of `<layer-list>`

Comment: inside <item> you can declare any other drawable, not only <bitmap>

Comment: Any reason for not using a relative layout/any other wrapper layouts that would allow easy positioning of items?

Comment: @Naveed I want to use this drawable as a background for `<EditText>` widget. It seems I'll have to do something like what you have suggested, but I wonder if there's simpler way